# bxslider carousel jumps too far

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

Hy

I set up a caroussel using BxSlider v4.1.2.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.products').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 240,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 4,
    slideMargin: 40,
    pager:true,
    speed:1500,
    auto:true
  });
});
```

I have 12 slides, so it should work perfectly with 3 steps, 4 slides per step. The Problem is now on every step it goes 5 slides forward. So you can't really see the 5th and the 10th slide. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I used paddings for my li-element. I removed them and now the calculation is correct!